# what is CLSID of COM object I just ran in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, com

I need to know CLSID of COM object which I just ran via `CreateObject("xxx.xxx")` how can I get it?

TIA!
Rafal

Comment: [CLSIDFromProgID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688386(v=vs.85).aspx) and [StringFromCLSID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683917(v=vs.85).aspx) properly imported into your VB app is likely what you seek. Use an API and avoid hammering the registry. I'm not familiar with VB.NET and whether it has this as a native API, but it likely does as part of the COM interop layer. If so, use that.

Comment: hm... And what is my ProgID() ? Is it that string which I pass to CreateObject ?

Comment: @Intelligent-Infrastructure: The ProgId is the string you pass to `CreateObject`, yes, your `xxx.xxx` in the above.

Comment: Yeah, what @T.J.Crowder said. its the "blah.blah" string. I'll be *amazed* if VB.NET doesn't have a native managed-code API to do this, so do some hunting and import the API's mentioned as a last resort.

Comment: CLSFromProgID() should work but I didn't find a straightforward way to implement it. Many problems in details (i.e. StrPtr which is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183544 ). But more or less it should work fine, however I'd love to see that there's an easier way (in Python I simply write Object.CLSID and get a string... )

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get that information directly from VB itself (e.g., as a side-effect or secondary result of calling `CreateObject`), but you can read the [registry entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd542719%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\xxx.xxx` and then look at its [`CLSID` key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms688628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: searching through registry is not a solution for me I need it robust:/

Comment: @Intelligent-Infrastructure: Searching through the registry **is** robust. It's how `CreateObject` works! (Not to mention the vast majority of Windows itself.)

Comment: Indeed.  Kinda pointless to use CreateObject() if you don't like how it works.  Add a reference to the type library instead.